# Llaves foráneas en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Debo crear dos tablas. La primera llamada usuario y la segunda llamada productos que debe tener una relación con la tabla usuarios y las estoy creando de la siguiente manera:

```
create table usuarios(
cod_user int not null,
name varchar(20),
constraint pk_usuarios
primary key (cod_user));
```

Esta tabla se crea correctamente, pero cuando intento crear la de productos me arroja este error `no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`

He aquí el script para crear la tabla de productos

```
create table productos(
cod_prod int not null,
name varchar (20),
brand varchar(20),
value number,
CONSTRAINT pk_productos 
PRIMARY KEY (cod_prod),
CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios 
FOREIGN KEY (name)
REFERENCES usuarios(name));
```

En realidad no entiendo qué error es o como se puede solucionar.

Comment: Ejecutas toda la sentencia junta?

Comment: No, primero creo la tabla de usuarios y luego la de productos

Comment: Por lo común, la asociación entre usarios y productos es de muchos entre  muchos.  En ese caso, se necista una tercera tabla, con dos llaves foráneas.  Una llave se refiere al usario y la otra al producto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta en que para que sea una `FOREIGN KEY` en la tabla principal tendria que ser `PRIMARY KEY` en tu caso haces referencia hacia el campo `NAME` en la tabla `usuarios` y no es `PRIMARY KEY` es por eso del error. Lo que puedes hacer es que hagas el `FOREIGN KEY` sobre la `PRIMARY KEY` de la tabla `usuarios`, de la siguiente manera:

```html
create table usuarios(
cod_user int not null,
name varchar(20),
constraint pk_usuarios
primary key (cod_user));

create table productos(
cod_prod int not null,
cod_user int not null,
brand varchar(20),
value number,
CONSTRAINT pk_productos 
PRIMARY KEY (cod_prod),
CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios 
FOREIGN KEY (cod_user)
REFERENCES usuarios(cod_user));
```

Ya después para la consulta debes de hacer un JOIN con las tablas para sacar el campo `NAME` de la tabla `usuarios`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se corrije así:

```
create table usuarios(
Usucod_user varchar2(20) is not null constraint pk_usucod_user primary key, 
name varchar(20)
);


create table productos(
fk_usucod_user varchar2(20) is not null,
cod_prod int not null,
name varchar (20),
brand varchar(20),
value number,
CONSTRAINT pk_productos PRIMARY KEY (cod_prod),
CONSTRAINT fk_usucod_user FOREIGN KEY (fk_usucod_user) REFERENCES usuarios(Usucod_user));
```

Creo que te faltaba hacer la referencia hacia la tabla usuarios, como clave foránea hacia la clave primaria.